# Replacing a light kit on a ceiling fan with a cap?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I want to remove the light kit from a hunter fan.  What product do I use to cover the opening where the light kit was attached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major problem with this are *finding* those caps. Wherever that fan was purchased, I'd be surprised if they sold let alone had any caps... I wish you the best of luck in your search though

I've done many fan installs for people and have those instances too, where a person just wanted that light kit removed and the cap replaced. I got lucky a couple of times where people had their original caps.

The other times when there was no hope finding caps I've modified the light kit by removing the lights in them and capping off the holes left behind with flat head or round head carriage bolts, with nuts behind them. Painted to match the repaired area, of course.

Not too bad of a look, I believe.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I have emailed Hunter fans and given them the model number of the fan.  They say they can provide the correct end cap, but we will see it that is true.  I hope so!

Answer (score 0):

Try googling "hunter ceiling fan end cap". There are a few that show up but matching them to your fan will be tough. You might just have to be creative and look around the house for something that will fit.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I have emailed Hunter fans and given them the model number of the fan.  They say they can provide the correct end cap, but we will see it that is true.  I hope so!

Answer (score 0):

Menards! Just received my cap today.Took less than a week. Half dozen colors. $11
Casablanca but Hunter fits. Very nice cap